# What is the equivalent syntax of EXISTSNODE in PostgreSQL

Tags: xml, postgresql

I am trying to convert below Oracle query into PostgreSQL but didn't find any solution.

```
 EXISTSNODE( p_candidate_xml, '//h:Candidate/h:CandidatePerson/h:UserArea/h:GOVT_SpecialHiringAuthorities/h:GOVT_SpecialHiringOptions[text() = "MILSPOUSE" or text() = "MILSPOUSEOS"]', ns )
```

I found xmlexists function but it's not accepting ns

Here ns-> namespace

Answer (score 0):

[`xpath_exists()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING) is probably what you are looking for. You haven't shown us the input XML, but something like this should work:

```
xpath_exists(
   p_candidate_xml, 
   '//h:Candidate/h:CandidatePerson/h:UserArea/h:GOVT_SpecialHiringAuthorities/h:GOVT_SpecialHiringOptions[text() = "MILSPOUSE" or text() = "MILSPOUSEOS"]', 
   ARRAY[ARRAY['h', 'http://example.com'] );
```